# How to filter ObservableCollection from various textbox (Multiple Criteria)?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, filter, observablecollection

I have a `ListView` that I'm filling with an `ObservableCollection`

I'm filtering the list from text entered in a `TextBox`

Here's a section of the code I'm using:

```
    private void Filter_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
           view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Elementos_Lista.ItemsSource);
           view.Filter = null;
           view.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterList);
    }
```

This works okay if I want to filter a list by just one criteria, but whenever I want to mix more than 1 textbox to do the filtering it always filters based on the ItemsSource, and not the current result set, meaning that there's no accumulation of criteria.

Here's my FilterList method.

```
 ItemDetail item = obj as ItemDetail;  
 if (item == null) return false;
 string  textFilter = txtFilter.Text; 
 if (textFilter.Trim().Length == 0) return true; //this returns the unfiltered results.
 if ((item.problema.ToLower().Contains(textFilter.ToLower()))) return true;  
 return false;
```

Is there a way to filter the ObservableCollection (view) by multiple criteria, that aren't always provided at the same time?.

I have tried to change the FilterList method to evaluate various textboxes, but I would have to make an IF statement to check all the possibilities of matching the criteria.

```
(filter1=value , filter2=value) OR 
(filter1=value , filter2=empty) OR 
(filter1=empty , filter2=value)
```

And since I'm planning to filter by at least 5 different controls, that wouldn't be fun at all.

Example:

```
List:
Maria, Age:26
Jesus, Age:15
Angela, Age:15
```

First Filter

```
Filters:
Name: //Empty
Age: 15

Result:
Jesus, Age:15
Angela, Age:15
```

Second Filter:

```
Filters:
Name: Jesus
Age: 15

Result:
Jesus, Age:15
```

What I'm trying to do is to apply filters to the already filtered collection, and not the original one, and this approach overwrites the applied filter with the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's see, I had something similar lying around here...

```
[ContractClass(typeof(CollectionViewFilterContracts<>))]
public interface ICollectionViewFilter<in T> where T : class
{
    bool FilterObject(T obj);
}
```

Contracts are optional of course ([CodeContracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/))

```
    [ContractClassFor(typeof(ICollectionViewFilter<>))]
    public abstract class CollectionViewFilterContracts<T> : ICollectionViewFilter<T> where T : class
    {
        public bool FilterObject(T obj)
        {
            Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null, "Filtered object can't be null");

            return default(bool);
        }
    }
```

And then the base implementation, you're using only strings for comparison as far as I can tell, so here's string-only version:

```
public abstract class CollectionFilterBase<T> : ICollectionViewFilter<T> where T : class
    {

        private readonly Dictionary<string, string> filters = new Dictionary<string, string>(10);
        private readonly PropertyInfo[] properties;

        protected CollectionFilterBase()
        {
             properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        }        

        protected void AddFilter(string memberName, string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                filters.Remove(memberName);
                return;
            }

            filters[memberName] = value;
        }

        public virtual bool FilterObject(T objectToFilter)
        {
             foreach (var filterValue in filters)
             {
                 var property = properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == filterValue.Key);
                 if(property == null)
                     return false;

                 var propertyValue = property.GetValue(objectToFilter, null);
                 var stringValue = propertyValue == null ? null : propertyValue.ToString(); // or use string.Empty instead of null, depends what you're going to do with it.
                 // Now you have the property value and you have your 'filter' value in filterValue.Value, do the check, return false if it's not what you're looking for.
                 //The filter will run through all selected (non-empty) filters and if all of them check out, it will return true.
             }

            return true;
        }
  }
```

Now some meaningful implementation, let's say this is your class, for simplicity:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

The filter implementation is - at the same time - the view model behind the view containing all your 'filtering' controls, so you bind the text box values to the properties accordingly.

```
public class PersonFilter : CollectionFilterBase<Person>
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            name = value;
            //NotifyPropertyChanged somehow, I'm using Caliburn.Micro most of the times, so:
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
            AddFilter("Name", Name);            
        }
    }
    private int age;
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return age;
        }
        set
        {
            age = value;
            //Same as above, notify
            AddFilter("Age", Age.ToString()) // only a string filter...
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have a `PersonFilter` object instance in your view model.

```
ICollectionViewFilter<Person> personFilter = new PersonFilter();
```

Then you just have to use the `Filter` event on the `CollectionView` to some method in the view model, e.g.:

```
CollectionView.Filter += FilterPeople

private void FilterPeople(object obj)
{
    var person = obj as Person;
    if(person == null)
        return false;
    return personFilter.FilterObject(person);
}
```

Filter names have to be the same as the property names on the filtered object. :)

And of course you'll have to call the `CollectionView.Refresh();` somewhere, you can move it to the filter (e.g. when the property changes, you can call `CollectionView.Refresh()` to see the changes immediately), you can call it in the event handler, however you want.

It's quite straightforward, although the performance could be better. Unless you're filtering a metric ton of data with a few dozen filters, you shouldn't have too many problems with adjusting and using the snippets. :)